# Android multiple checkboxes wanting to check if it is clicked the first time

Tags: android, checkbox, boolean-logic

I have a bunch of checkboxes and I have the same method for each checkbox. What I'm trying to do is to have a checkbox if that particular checkbox was checked for the first time. What's happening is I think the counter is still going up even though the checkbox was not checked but others were. So, I'm trying to have the checkboxes go from red to yellow to green (it starts as red), but when one of the checkboxes is checked it turns yellow which is what I want, but if I try to check another checkbox, it will turn green instead of yellow. I tried having a boolean, but I'm not exactly sure how to have it know if that particular checkbox was checked the first time and set the counter to 0. If I set the counter to 0 inside of the onClick method, it will just keep being 0. So, I am wondering if there is a way to know if the checkbox is checked for the first time and have it set to 0. I want to be efficient with my code and to not have a separate counter for each of the checkboxes. I have tried researching this problem but can't find any help. Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks!

```
public void checked(CheckBox checkBox){
    if (checkBox.isChecked()){
        count++;
    } else if (!checkBox.isChecked()){
        checkBox.setChecked(true);
        count++;
    }
    if (count == 1){
        checkBox.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.custom_yellow_checkbox);
    }
    if (count == 2){
        checkBox.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.custom_green_checkbox);
    }
    if (count > 2){
        count = 0;
        checkBox.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.custom_red_checkbox);
    }
}


chkDownload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            checked(chkDownload);
        }
    });

chkGetCalendar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            checked(chkGetCalendar);
        }
    });

chkStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            checked(chkStart);
        }
    });
```

Comment: you will need a counter for each checkbox. What's happening is `count` gets increased when you click `chkDownload` and increases again if you press `chkStart`

Comment: Is there a way to have the counter in the method like checked(Checkbox checkbox, int counter) and have the individual counters in that parameter with checked(chkStart, count1); checked(chkDownload, count2);? I don't want to put what is in the checked method in each of the checkboxes because I feel that isn't very efficient.

Comment: Check my answer if this is what you are looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is:

```
int downloadCount = 0;
int calendarCount = 0;
int startCount = 0;

public void checked(CheckBox checkBox,int count){
    if (checkBox.isChecked()){
        count++;
    } else if (!checkBox.isChecked()){
        checkBox.setChecked(true);
        count++;
    }
    if (count == 1){
        checkBox.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.custom_yellow_checkbox);
    }
    if (count == 2){
        checkBox.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.custom_green_checkbox);
    }
    if (count > 2){
        count = 0;
        checkBox.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.custom_red_checkbox);
    }
}


chkDownload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            checked(chkDownload,downloadCount);
        }
    });

chkGetCalendar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            checked(chkGetCalendar,calendarCount);
        }
    });

chkStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            checked(chkStart,startCount);
        }
    });
```

EDIT

What you can do then is return the count so it retains it.

eg:

```
public int checked(CheckBox checkBox,int count){
    if (checkBox.isChecked()){
        count++;
    } else if (!checkBox.isChecked()){
        checkBox.setChecked(true);
        count++;
    }
    if (count == 1){
        checkBox.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.custom_yellow_checkbox);
    }
    if (count == 2){
        checkBox.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.custom_green_checkbox);
    }
    if (count > 2){
        count = 0;
        checkBox.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.custom_red_checkbox);
    }
    return count;
}

chkDownload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        downloadCount = checked(chkDownload,downloadCount);
    }
});
```

> I'm not sure what your code looks like but I just built this and it works:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    int downloadCount = 0;
    int calendarCount = 0;
    int startCount = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final CheckBox chkDownload = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chkDownload);
        final CheckBox chkGetCalendar = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chkGetCalendar);
        final CheckBox chkStart = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chkStart);

        chkDownload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                downloadCount = checked(chkDownload, downloadCount);
            }
        });

        chkGetCalendar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                calendarCount = checked(chkGetCalendar, calendarCount);
            }
        });

        chkStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startCount = checked(chkStart, startCount);
            }
        });

    }

    public int checked(CheckBox checkBox, int count) {

        if (checkBox.isChecked()) {

            count++;

        } else if (!checkBox.isChecked()) {

            checkBox.setChecked(true);
            count++;

        }

        if (count == 1) {
            checkBox.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.ic_menu_camera);
        }
        if (count == 2) {
            checkBox.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.ic_menu_gallery);
        }
        if (count > 2) {
            count = 0;
            checkBox.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.ic_menu_manage);
        }
        return count;
    }

}
```

Comment: I tried that before, and the checkbox doesn't turn green because count is never initialized. That was my problem. Do you think there is a way for it to be initialized without it being initialized every time the user clicks on the checkbox?

Comment: Still not turning green when clicked the second time. It is still yellow. I think it has to be initialized somehow. I did change my return type in the checked method to int, so that it would work and not have errors, but it still didn't work. Sorry.

Comment: @Karna Where is your code? is it in an activity? fragment? check my edit. I have created a test app with 1 activity and it works by changing the pictures

Comment: Works great! Thanks so much!